# Exporting LaTeX fracments - The right way!

Tags: org-mode, org-export

### I mess up my non edited question. Here is the right question

In the previous version of the question I mixed two different things I was having problems with.

I was trying to export a literate `LaTeX` code using `#+begin_latex ... #+end_latex` syntax, and it was note the right thing to do. *Thanks to t-verron for answer my doubt* even when I posted the wrong question.

Sorry for screwing this up!

---

I'm trying to set specific attributes for LaTeX in an =org= file, but the `#+attr_latex` command does not work (see the first edit below)... moreover, only the =verse=, =export=, =center=, =source=, =example=, =quote= and =comment= seems to be available.

Is this a problem of =org-9.0= ?

Setup: Emacs 24.4.1, org 9.0 (from org repo, with org-plus-contrib)

---

**First Edit:** To my understanding, the `attr_latex` is supposed to assure that the code in between is exported literally. However, once my file is exported, I get a `\begin{latex} ... \end{latex}` environment (which inserts a `\LaTeX` command before the code.

The following code in `org`

```
#+BEGIN_LaTeX
  \begin{dmath}
    \label{4dfull}
    S[{\Gamma},T,A] =
    \int\dn{4}{x}\bigg[
      B_1\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\mu}{}_{\rho} T^{\nu,\alpha\beta}T^{\rho,\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}
      +B_2\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\sigma}{}_\rho T^{\beta,\mu\nu}T^{\rho,\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\sigma\beta\gamma\delta}
      +B_3\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\mu}{}_{\rho} T^{\nu,\rho\sigma}A_\sigma
      +B_4\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\sigma}{}_\rho T^{\rho,\mu\nu}A_\sigma
      +B_5\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\rho}{}_\rho T^{\sigma,\mu\nu}A_\sigma
      +C_1\, R_{\mu\rho}{}^{\mu}{}_\nu \nabla_\sigma T^{\nu,\rho\sigma}
      +C_2\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\rho}{}_\rho \nabla_\sigma T^{\sigma,\mu\nu} 
      +D_1\, T^{\alpha,\mu\nu}T^{\beta,\rho\sigma}\nabla_\gamma T^{(\lambda, \kappa) \gamma}\epsilon_{\beta\mu\nu\lambda}\epsilon_{\alpha\rho\sigma\kappa}
      +D_2\,T^{\alpha,\mu\nu}T^{\lambda,\beta\gamma}\nabla_\lambda T^{\delta,\rho\sigma}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
      +D_3\,T^{\mu,\alpha\beta}T^{\lambda,\nu\gamma}\nabla_\lambda T^{\delta,\rho\sigma}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
      +D_4\,T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}T^{\kappa,\rho\sigma}\nabla_{(\lambda} A_{\kappa)} \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
      +D_5\,T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}\nabla_{[\lambda}T^{\kappa,\rho\sigma} A_{\kappa]} \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
      +D_6\,T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}A_\nu\nabla_{(\lambda} A_{\mu)}
      +D_7\,T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}A_\lambda\nabla_{[\mu} A_{\nu]} 
      +E_1\,\nabla_{(\rho} T^{\rho,\mu\nu}\nabla_{\sigma)} T^{\sigma,\lambda\kappa}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\lambda\kappa}
      +E_2\,\nabla_{(\lambda} T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu)} A_\nu
      +T^{\alpha,\beta\gamma}T^{\delta,\eta\kappa}T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}T^{\rho,\sigma\tau}
      \Big(F_1\,\epsilon_{\beta\gamma\eta\kappa}\epsilon_{\alpha\rho\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\delta\lambda\sigma\tau}
      +F_2\,\epsilon_{\beta\lambda\eta\kappa}\epsilon_{\gamma\rho\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\alpha\delta\sigma\tau}\Big) 
      +F_3\, T^{\rho,\alpha\beta}T^{\gamma,\mu\nu}T^{\lambda,\sigma\tau}A_\tau \epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\lambda}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
      +F_4\,T^{\eta,\alpha\beta}T^{\kappa,\gamma\delta}A_\eta A_\kappa\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\bigg],
  \end{dmath}
#+END_LaTeX
```

is exported to LaTeX as

```
\begin{LaTeX}
\begin{dmath}
  \label{4dfull}
  S[{\Gamma},T,A] =
  \int\dn{4}{x}\bigg[
    B_1\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\mu}{}_{\rho} T^{\nu,\alpha\beta}T^{\rho,\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}
    +B_2\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\sigma}{}_\rho T^{\beta,\mu\nu}T^{\rho,\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\sigma\beta\gamma\delta}
    +B_3\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\mu}{}_{\rho} T^{\nu,\rho\sigma}A_\sigma
    +B_4\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\sigma}{}_\rho T^{\rho,\mu\nu}A_\sigma
    +B_5\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\rho}{}_\rho T^{\sigma,\mu\nu}A_\sigma
    +C_1\, R_{\mu\rho}{}^{\mu}{}_\nu \nabla_\sigma T^{\nu,\rho\sigma}
    +C_2\, R_{\mu\nu}{}^{\rho}{}_\rho \nabla_\sigma T^{\sigma,\mu\nu} 
    +D_1\, T^{\alpha,\mu\nu}T^{\beta,\rho\sigma}\nabla_\gamma T^{(\lambda, \kappa) \gamma}\epsilon_{\beta\mu\nu\lambda}\epsilon_{\alpha\rho\sigma\kappa}
    +D_2\,T^{\alpha,\mu\nu}T^{\lambda,\beta\gamma}\nabla_\lambda T^{\delta,\rho\sigma}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
    +D_3\,T^{\mu,\alpha\beta}T^{\lambda,\nu\gamma}\nabla_\lambda T^{\delta,\rho\sigma}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
    +D_4\,T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}T^{\kappa,\rho\sigma}\nabla_{(\lambda} A_{\kappa)} \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
    +D_5\,T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}\nabla_{[\lambda}T^{\kappa,\rho\sigma} A_{\kappa]} \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
    +D_6\,T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}A_\nu\nabla_{(\lambda} A_{\mu)}
    +D_7\,T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}A_\lambda\nabla_{[\mu} A_{\nu]} 
    +E_1\,\nabla_{(\rho} T^{\rho,\mu\nu}\nabla_{\sigma)} T^{\sigma,\lambda\kappa}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\lambda\kappa}
    +E_2\,\nabla_{(\lambda} T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu)} A_\nu
    +T^{\alpha,\beta\gamma}T^{\delta,\eta\kappa}T^{\lambda,\mu\nu}T^{\rho,\sigma\tau}
    \Big(F_1\,\epsilon_{\beta\gamma\eta\kappa}\epsilon_{\alpha\rho\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\delta\lambda\sigma\tau}
    +F_2\,\epsilon_{\beta\lambda\eta\kappa}\epsilon_{\gamma\rho\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\alpha\delta\sigma\tau}\Big) 
    +F_3\, T^{\rho,\alpha\beta}T^{\gamma,\mu\nu}T^{\lambda,\sigma\tau}A_\tau \epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\lambda}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}
    +F_4\,T^{\eta,\alpha\beta}T^{\kappa,\gamma\delta}A_\eta A_\kappa\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\bigg],
\end{dmath}
\end{LaTeX}
```

and shown as `PDF` as (notice the word `LaTeX` just before the equation)

[image]

In addition, when I want to use `pcomplete` to insert the `attr_latex`, it is not shown as an available option.

**Q1:** How can the appearance of the word LaTeX be avoided?

**Q2:** What should I do to have the `attr_latex` in the `pcomplete` setup?

Comment: "does not work" is not very clear. Can you provide an example that illustrates what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Tyler I've added a detailed explanation of the problem. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: In org 9, the syntax is `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex... #+END_EXPORT`, maybe that's the cause of your problem. Otherwise, your example is not complete, it would be interesting to see what you have in the org file before the latex block.

Comment: You keep mentioning `attr_latex`, but it doesn't even appear in your example? It's still not clear what you're asking

Comment: Some words about the effects you are seeing: The elisp-function `org-latex-special-block` of `ox-latex` kicks in here. The string `LaTeX` in `#+BEGIN_LaTeX` is irrelevant. It is just the name of a special block. You could also name it `#+BEGIN_myLaTeX` and you would get `\begin{myLaTeX}` in the document. LaTeX transforms `\begin{LaTeX}` to the command `\LaTeX`. That is the reason why you get `LaTeX` in your typeset document where `\begin{LaTeX}` occurs in your LaTeX-source file.